# Is it possible to remove requests from scrapys scheduler queue?

Tags: python, scrapy

Is it possible to remove requests from scrapy's scheduler queue? I have a working routine that limits crawling to a certain domain for a set amount of time. It's working in the sense that it will not yield anymore links once the time limit was hit but as the queue can already contain thousands of requests for the domain I'd like to remove them from the scheduler queue once the time limit is hit.

Comment: Could you write your own [Downloader Middleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.24/topics/downloader-middleware.html) that  controllably sends requests to ground?

Comment: That's not a bad idea, I will certainly give it a shot. I'll post back when its done. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like the kind of job for a [frontera](http://frontera.readthedocs.org) backend.

Comment: @elias  Sounds interesting.  Is there a simple "toss my requests" or "clear my scheduler" with `frontera`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay so I ended up following the suggestion from [@rickgh12hs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1409374) and wrote my own Downloader Middleware:

```
from scrapy.exceptions import IgnoreRequest
import tldextract

class clearQueueDownloaderMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        domain_obj = tldextract.extract(request.url)
        just_domain = domain_obj.registered_domain
        if(just_domain in spider.blocked):
            print "Blocked domain: %s (url: %s)" % (just_domain, request.url)
            raise IgnoreRequest("URL blocked: %s" % request.url)
```

spider.blocked is a class list variable that contains blocked domains preventing any further downloads from the blocked domains. Seem to work great, cudos to [@rickgh12hs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1409374)!

Comment: Amazing the Downloader Middleware is that concise.  Cool!

Comment: This doesn't remove the request object right? It just processes it when it's queued up?

Comment: Correct, it does not remove the request object. It will just ignore requests containing the blocked domain.