# When parsing many websites, how to make Scrapy stop yielding requests in the for loop if data is found and move to the next website

Tags: python, parsing, scrapy

So, I am parsing emails from many websites

1)

I take them from the front page and from the contacts section ('kont' or 'cont' in hrefs)
There could be many links with 'kont' or 'cont' at the front page
I don't want to visit all of them in the "for" loop

I would like the program to go to another website when the data is found in one of those links (email_list_2 != []). **how to do that?**

2)

There is some redundancy in the code, I yield data at the front page because I am afraid the request from the for loop would be unsuccessful, in which case I will lose data from the front page.

Can I just yield {'site': site,
'email_list_1': email_list_1,
'email_list_2': []} if data is not found

or

{'site': site,
'email_list_1': email_list_1,
'email_list_2': ['xyz']} if data is found without double yielding?

Please help

Regards,

```
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'enrichment'
    start_urls = website_list

        
    def parse(self, response):
        site = response.url
        data = response.text 
        email_list_1 = emailRegex.findall(data)
        yield {'lvl': '1',
            'site': site,
            'email_list_1': email_list_1,
            'email_list_2': [],
            }  
        
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'lxml')
        
        for link in soup.find_all('a'): 

            raw_url = link.get('href') 
            full_url = str(site) + str(raw_url)
    
            if (re.search('cont', full_url) != None or 
                re.search('kont', full_url) != None):  
                
                yield scrapy.Request(url=full_url,
                                     callback=self.parse_2d_level,
                                     meta={'site':  site,'email_list_1': email_list_1 } 
                                     )

 
    def parse_2d_level(self, response):
        site = response.meta['site']
        email_list_1 = response.meta['email_list_1']
        data_2 = response.text
        email_list_2 = emailRegex.findall(data_2)
        
        yield {'lvl': '2',
            'site': site,
            'email_list_1': email_list_1,
            'email_list_2': email_list_2,
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but here it goes:

1 - You want to scrape PAGE1, look for `'cont'` or `'kont'` and if these components exists, make a new request for PAGE2. In PAGE2 you search for a `email_list_2` and `yield` results. You asked:

> I would like the program to go to another website when the data is
> found in one of those links (email_list_2 != []). how to do that?

What website do you want it to go? Is it a follow on the page you are already scraping? Is it another website in your `start_urls`?

At current state, after parsing PAGE2 (on `parse_2d_level` method) your spider will `yield` results, whether it found values for `email_list_2` or not. If there are other requests on queue, scrapy will go on to execute those, if there aren't, the spider will end.

2- You want to make sure the data you already found before the loop is yielded in case the request from inside the loop fails. Since you said

> the request from the for loop would be unsuccessful

I'll assume you are **only worried about the REQUEST failure**, there are other ways your parsing could fail.
For failed request you can catch and handle the issue with a scrapy signal called spider_error, take a look [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html).

3-You should take a look at Scrapy's [selectors](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html), they are a very powerful tool. You don't need beautiful soup for the parsing, and the Selectors will help a lot with the precision.

Comment: 《《《What website do you want it to go? Is it a follow on the page you are already scraping? Is it another website in your start_urls?》》》 - another website in my start_urls

Comment: thank you very much for the reply! there could be several links with "cont", "kont" components, for example, 10 links. the spider found emails_list_2 in the second link. there are 8 more links in the for loop, don't want to waste computing power if email_list_2 != []. want the spider to go to another website in my start_urls

Comment: At current state your spider should already scrape every URL you have in `start_urls`. Once you yield the Request object in the first method they are put on the Scheduler's queue, since scrapy works asynchronously there isn't a trivial way for you to stop those requests after filling `email_list_2`. You can try a workaround like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30438650/is-it-possible-to-remove-requests-from-scrapys-scheduler-queue

Comment: thanks alot! is there any good resource you can recommend on scrapy? I am new to this framework and documentation is not always enough to get a head around

Comment: Maybe https://www.scrapinghub.com/guides/, I can't reccommend anything, as I usually go by the documentation or StackOverflow. Please accept my answer by clicking the checkmark.