# How to make the crawler pass the domain when it has extracted what it was searching for?

Tags: scrapy

I have a crawler browsing from link to link, searching for a specified item to scrape. I want to implement that he should pass the whole domain (leave that website) when one has been found and proceed with the other sites which are in the queue. How can that be handled?

Practically speaking: So when the crawler is at [www.example.com/products/news/..](http://www.example.com/products/news/..). and finds the item to look for, it should leave [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and not return to it again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30438650/939364 would be a good starting point.